# Azure as a Facebook Platform

Tags: facebook, azure

How is Azure as a platform for Facebook Apps? I am looking in comparison to GAE (Google App Engine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me they're both good platforms for Facebook apps, since they support building web applications which can scale if they become popular.  I won't compare further, since I'm obviously biased.  (I work on Windows Azure.)

However, if you're interested, I wrote a blog post about my own Facebook app running in Windows Azure: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/facebook-apps-on-windows-azure.  That one's written in .NET, but we support PHP as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a facebook app hosted on Azure.

I dont think there are any facebook specific benefits of Azure over Google App Engine, but azure is a fantastic platform for rapid roll out of test applications.

A big part of the answer will depend on your coding stack of choice. Will azure supports most languages already, at the moment, some are better than others in terms of tools.